# Problem integrating QML project into C++ code

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I don't know a lot about qt so please bear with me.
I have a qt widgets application that I made as a part of a project , a friend has a Qt quick applications project which I'd like to integrate into my qt widgets app.This is what I've added in my mainwindow.cpp

```
QQuickView *view = new QQuickView();
    QWidget *container = QWidget::createWindowContainer(view, this);
    container->setMinimumSize(300, 200);
    container->setMaximumSize(600, 400);

    view->setSource(QUrl("/maps/main.qml")); file.
    ui->qmlwidget->addWidget(container);
```

However , the integration doesn't work correctly.The qt quick project is a map which takes coordinates as inputs and then points them on the map.It works as expected when it is run standalone but when I integrate it using the above method , clicking the button which is supposed to point out the location does nothing.This is the Qt quick app code:

**gmap.cpp**

```
    #include "gmap.h"

gmap::gmap()
{

}

void gmap::setData(QString lat,QString lang)
{
    qDebug(lat.toLatin1());

    emit getLat(lat.toDouble());
    emit getLang(lang.toDouble());
}
```

**gmap.h**

```
    #ifndef GMAP_H
#define GMAP_H

#include <QObject>

class gmap : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT


public:
    gmap();


signals:
    void getLat(double lat);
    void getLang(double lang);


public slots:
    void setData(QString lat,QString lang);



};
#endif // GMAP_H
```

**main.qml**

```
    import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.2;
import QtPositioning 5.6;
import QtLocation 5.9
import Qt3D.Input 2.1
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2;


Window {
    width: Qt.platform.os == "android" ? Screen.width : 512
    height: Qt.platform.os == "android" ? Screen.height : 512
    visible: true

    Plugin {
        id: mapPlugin
        name: "osm"
        PluginParameter {
             name: 'osm.mapping.highdpi_tiles'
            value: !!1      }
    }

    Connections{

        target: gmap
        onGetLat : mapmarker.center.latitude = lat

    }
    Connections{

        target: gmap
        onGetLang : mapmarker.center.longitude = lang

    }
    Connections{

        target: gmap
        onGetLang : map.center = QtPositioning.coordinate(mapmarker.center.latitude,mapmarker.center.longitude,150);



    }

    Map {
        id: map
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.rightMargin: -15
        anchors.bottomMargin: -10
        anchors.leftMargin: 15
        anchors.topMargin: 10
        plugin: mapPlugin
        center: QtPositioning.coordinate() // NSUT
        zoomLevel: 14
        activeMapType: supportedMapTypes[2]


        Button {
            x: 389
            y: 445
            text: "ADD MARKER"
            anchors.right: parent.right
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
            anchors.bottomMargin: 27
            anchors.rightMargin: 23
            padding: 7
            onClicked: gmap.setData(textField.text,textField1.text)
        }



        MapCircle {

            id: mapmarker
                center {
                    latitude: 28.6078
                    longitude: 77.0406


                }
                radius: 50.0
                color: 'green'
                border.width: 3
        }


        TextField {
            id: textField
            x: 176
            y: 397
            text: qsTr("")
            anchors.right: parent.right
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
            anchors.bottomMargin: 75
            anchors.rightMargin: 136
        }

        TextField {
            id: textField1
            x: 176
            y: 445
            anchors.right: parent.right
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
            anchors.bottomMargin: 27
            anchors.rightMargin: 136
            font.hintingPreference: Font.PreferDefaultHinting
        }


    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

in your qml side,there is no item that was named to gmap. you must first add a gmap object to rootContext

```
gmap newGmap;
view->rootContext()->setContextProperty("gmap", &newGmap);
```